# Excel formula to return cell value if multiple criteria met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to automate the copying of long term economic data from one spreadsheet (the original data source) to a new workbook that tracks changes over the past decade only.

The first image is of the original data source. Each economic region (ECO1, ECO2) has its own unique Series ID:

[image]

The second image is of the new workbook:

[image]

I would like to insert a formula into the second workbook that matches the listed Series ID to the original dataset, then matches the listed date in the same manner, in order to return the relevant cell value (e.g. if the Series ID is **A2336355R** and the date is **June 2007**, the formula returns the value **1.7** as listed in cell F20 of the original workbook).

Such a formula would allow me to simply change the dates in the new workbook (e.g. changes over the previous ten years only) and have the cell values update accordingly.

Comment: Super User is not a script writing service. Rather, it is a place to get help with what you already have and where you are stuck. Please [edit] your question to include what you have already tried and we will help from there.

Comment: At the time of writing I didn't know where to start, so the explanation above is adequate. Nevertheless, tonnu's response led me to a solution which I will answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that using an [INDEX MATCH MATCH](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match-match/) formula answers my query.

Specifically, the following formula copies data from the original workbook to the second one, and will update all figures if I change the dates or Series IDs in the second workbook:

```
=INDEX('[original-data-source.xlsx]Data1'!$B$3:$DW$100,MATCH($A5,'[original-data-source.xlsx]Data1'!$A$3:$A$100,0),MATCH(B$4,'[original-data-source.xlsx]Data1'!$B$2:$DW$2,0))
```

This formula is broken down further below. In short, it is essentially:

- **INDEX** - Select the array that you wish to pull data from (in the case above, the original data source workbook)
- **MATCH (both times)** - Select the value (i.e. cell) in the *second workbook* that you want Excel to find in the *original data source workbook*, then select the array where Excel will look to find the value, and *then* put '0' in as the last argument to ensure an exact match

In the formula above, the **INDEX** has selected all the cells from B3 across and down in the original data source workbook.

The first **MATCH** function selects the date in the second workbook, then searches for an exact match in column A of the original data source workbook.

The second **MATCH** function selects the Series ID in the second workbook, then searches for an exact match in row 2 of the original data source workbook.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done easily with a combination of vlookup

vlookup's input requires the lookup value, the array, and the index column

that index column can be automated using hlookup, i.e. it will tell vlookup which column to return the value based on the Series ID

then simply use vlookup to match the date to the column

easy peasy

Comment: I've found this [link](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-the-vlookup-hlookup-combination-formula/) but I'm not having any luck getting the combination to work. Also, is it possible to create a formula without the need for a new row for column numbers?

Comment: Great first answer, but it needs some improving. Super User is looking for detailed answers. This would be improved by using example formulas, citing a reference, etc. Take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.